# Could I use memcpy to the pointer which I new it before？

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

for example, I try to write my own `vector`, so I just write its `assign` function like this

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T> :: assign(T *start, T *end)
{
    if (end - start > _capacity)
    {
        resize(end - start);
    }
    _size = end - start;
    delete []ptr;
    ptr = new T[_capacity];
    memcpy(ptr, start, end - start);
}
```

I have new the pointer `ptr` before, but I can copy all I what between the pointer `start` and `end`

why? Thankyou very much.

Comment: Only if `T` is a trivially-copyable type... (Read as: No, bad idea.)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7536230/636019).

Comment: This does not provide the strong exception guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem is that this only works for simple types (read POD).
Anything with a constructor/destructor needs to have them called.

Second this is not exception safe.
It does not even provide the basic guarantee let a lone the strong guarantee.

You need to do all exception unsafe work before modifying the object. This means the `new` must be done **before** you modify the object (and definitely before the free). Otherwise you could potentially throw leaving the object in an invalid state (that might not seem bad, but what if you catch the exception and continue you now have an object that contains a pointer to released memory).

So even if you use `std::copy()` you still have done the wrong thing.
Personally I think the suggestion of std::copy() is a red herring. It will copy the data correctly but you are still writing your method badly. You need to use a twist on the copy and swap idium.

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T> :: assign(T *start, T *end)
{
    Vector<T> tmp(start, end);  // construct a temp object that allocates the memory.



    swap(tmp);                  // Swap the current object and the tmp objects data.
                                // When the tmp object goes out of scope it will delete
                                // what was the current objects data

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly fine to reuse the pointer in this way, but it is ***not*** safe to use memcpy here because you don't know what type T is.  If T is an object type like string or vector, this causes undefined behavior.

To fix this, change the line to

```
std::copy(start, end, ptr);
```

Which is the safe, C++ way of doing this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou, and I just found that the right way to use it is `std::copy(start, end, ptr);`

Comment: This is not a good idea. As it still leaves the `assign()` method providing no exception guarantee and thus it is a broken answer.

Comment: The order of args to `std::copy` is incorrect. It should be `std::copy(start, end, ptr);`, not `std::copy(ptr, start, end);`. In C++11, you can use `std::copy_n(start, _size, ptr)`.

Comment: @LokiAstari- Absolutely.  However, given that the OP's question was localized to this line, I decided to focus my answer on explaining why the memcpy was a bad idea.  Rewriting this entire function to be exception-safe would distract from that particular teaching point.